# Recommended approach for coupon assignment in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, sql, triggered-send

In SFMC, we are currently using claimrow() approach for coupon assignment but in past we have seen some issues with this where same coupons getting assigned to same subscribers since coupon email is real-time and triggered via API (hence there is a chance of multiple requests at the same time).

Is there any recommended approach that can be used to claim coupon and trigger email in real-time via API; something that can handle a lot of traffic?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with ClaimRow(), and the recommendation from experienced specialists was to not use it.

The recommended approach was to use the tried-and-true SQL JOIN merge between the Subscriber and Coupon DE (using ROW_NUMBER() to merge - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234470/merging-two-tables-with-no-unique-keys-without-row-number).

Whilst this is most useful for an existing list of coupons, as opposed to a live API request, could you consider an automation which does the following:

- STEP 1: Create target Subscriber DE, filtered by SQL
- STEP 2: SSJS API script to generate coupons for each Subscriber (record into Send or Coupon Log DE)
- STEP 3: Send email with coupons

Obviously with Automation Studio the quickest this can be batch run is once per hour. However, you could shift this to real-time by triggering the Automation with SFMC's API.

Comment: Hi Ryan, first of all thank you for sharing your thoughts. I did look into this a little bit, though it may solve for the coupon assignment (as a replacement for claimrow() function), my concern is how this will work in real-time. If real-time api call is triggering automation for each customer, what would happen if  multiple customer's calls are triggering the api to start the automation? automation may be in processing status and may not trigger for other customer or in other words, automation may work / activate based on per api call basis. Please let me know if i am overlooking something?

Comment: @kuml2 Yes, I agree that Automation load capacity is the unknown here. Stepping back to your original problem of the "same coupon gets assigned to same subscriber", do you mean the Coupon DE has duplicate rows or do you mean the same Coupon DE row is triggered as an email twice? If it's the former problem, can your API request code check whether the SubscriberKey has already generated a code recently (i.e. DE lookup) and stop the process if so?

Comment: Hi Ryan, in my use-case, API is triggering the triggered send email (which is the standard API call to triggered send API endpoint) and I have noticed that in rear cases when multiple API calls are made at the same time (since the experience for customers is real-time), same code is assigned to multiple subscribers (makes me think that claiming is not holding a code for subscriber, while it is being processed another request see the already in processed coupon code as available and hence end up with duplicates. That's my hypothesis.

Comment: Currently, this API trigger is coming from our website (web team) who is triggering the triggered send API endpoint, my concern with performing lookup is that web team will need to change the way API call is being made (something outside the scope of SFMC). I am trying to figure out if there is anything that an be done as a workaround with SFMC so we do not have to depend on any custom API call. Plus, I am not sure if lookup will work if same coupon is getting linked with multiple subs then lookup may return no assignment anyway.